# Does echarts has drill down option for all category of charts

Tags: echarts

I am going to use baidu echarts in my project, but till now not able to find drill down option in pie, bar and line charts.

Please help me, if anyone know the drill down option.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an `onClick`-handler for the chart- and this handler then changes the content of the chart. At least this is what i am using.

```
chart.on("click", (param) => {
 // Magic here
});
```

But to answer your question: No, it does not have a drill down option for all chart types.

Comment: Hi! I am desperately trying to find any example of implementing Echarts drill down. I'm using Vue and currently can detect a click on the component of the chart itself but I don't know what exactly I must retrive from its data after click. I cannot see any data about the particular data set.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement drill down with ajax calls, using the click event on the chart and it's parameters.
With the response you can init the chart and reload the options.